# Amplify fetchAuthSession does not return valid token for AWS API Gateway authentication

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using flutter and using amplify API to integrate with AWS Cognito. The authentication framework is completed successfully and I am able to register and login. Now I have to do lambda invocation through API Gateway in a secured way. I am able to make successful API calls using "authorizationType": "AWS_IAM", "API_KEY" however not able to make it work with "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS". I need to get the logged in user details in lambda so the only way to achieve this is to use AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS authorizationType. As per the documentation I am making the following entry in
**amplifyconfiguration.dart**

```
"api": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsAPIPlugin": {
                "lambdaapiplugin": {
                    "endpointType": "REST",
                    "endpoint": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev",
                    "region": "ap-south-1",
                    "authorizationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I made the api call also however it was giving {"message":"Unauthorized"}
I have extracted the token from the logged in user as shown below and set it in header as shown below

```
final session = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
        options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true),
);
AWSCognitoUserPoolTokens awsCognitoUserPoolTokens =
  (session as CognitoAuthSession).userPoolTokens!;
var requestObject = {};
var encodedRequestObject = jsonEncode(requestObject);

RestOptions options = RestOptions(
path: '/api-path',
apiName: 'lambdaapiplugin',
headers: {'Authorization': awsCognitoUserPoolTokens.idToken},
body: Uint8List.fromList(
  encodedRequestObject.codeUnits,
),
);

RestOperation restOperation = Amplify.API.post(restOptions: options);
RestResponse response = await restOperation.response;
```

I tried getting the idToken as well as accessToken from AWSCognitoUserPoolTokens and tried it on header directly on Postman that also didn't help. What is the correct way to get token from a logged in user in flutter using amplify